# Vimeo - Sending password via javascript api

Tags: javascript, video, passwords, vimeo, protected

i have embedded a protected vimeo video on a site.
Is there any method to send the password via JavaScript API instead of force the user to type it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This technique will expose the videos password to all users. The best technique is to mark your video as "hidden from vimeo" and "only embeddable on ". Then you can control any access restrictions on your own terms.

Comment: Do you know how the "only embeddable on" feature is implemented ? Is it really secure (immune to http header spoofing) ?

Comment: Is this still a valid option?