# Show password protected Vimeo video without password

Tags: vimeo

I have a client that insists on password protecting each Vimeo video with a different password. However, when embedded into their authenticated marketing site, they want them to show up without passwords. What we are doing as a stopgap is displaying password for the video right after the video. I have the password in the API but I cannot get it into the video. Is there not a way of playing the video without having the user enter the password?

I've tried JavaScript but because of the iframe this crosses domain boundaries and so can't be done for obvious security reasons.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066558/vimeo-sending-password-via-javascript-api) on StackOverflow suggests that there is an "only embeddable" option. But I can't find it.

Comment: The "Hide from vimeo.com" privacy setting is only available to Plus users and higher, docs here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to override the password prompt in the Vimeo Player iframe, via the API or any other official method.

Your client may be better served by a different privacy setting, like "Hide from vimeo.com" that makes the video only playable when embedded -- for extra protection, you could then set the embed privacy to "Only on domains I allow" so the video only plays embedded on specific websites and domains.

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview